# Code to count the number of sequential characters

Tags: bash, awk

For example, if the input is `aabcca`, the output needs to be `a2b1c2a1` not `a3b1c2`

I originally wrote this -

```
echo "aabcca" > file.txt
a=0
b=0
c=0

while IFS= read -r -n1 char
do

[ "$char" == "a" ] && (( a++ )) 
[ "$char" == "b" ] && (( b++ ))
[ "$char" == "c" ] && (( c++ ))
done < file.txt
echo "a${a}b${b}c${c}"
```

But this outputs `a3b1c2`. I want `a2b1c2a1`.

Comment: No serious contribution: `echo "aabcca" | sed 's/./&\n/g;' | sed '/^$/d' | uniq -c | awk '{print $2 $1}' ORS=''`

Comment: you're only outputing 3 pairs of values, when you want 4 pairs. More importantly, you'll need to maintain some sort of state so your script knows that you have transitioned from one char to another, which should reset the previous char, i.e. you need more statements like `a=0` interspersed. .  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

count=0
read -r -n1 prev_char < file.txt

while IFS= read -r -n1 char
do
    if [ "$prev_char" != "$char" ]
    then
        printf "%c%d" "$prev_char" "$count"
        count=0
    fi

    prev_char="$char"
    count=$((count + 1))

done < file.txt

printf "\n"
```

Comment: That would be extremely slow. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`, you may do this:

```
awk '{
   p=c=""
   for (i=1; i<=length(); ++i) {
      f=substr($0, i, 1)
      if (p != "" && f != p) {
         printf "%s", p c
         c = 0
      }
      ++c
      p = f
   }
   print p c
}' file.txt
```

```
a2b1c2a1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an one-liner way to do it:

```
tr '\n' ' ' < file.txt | fold -w1 | uniq -c | awk '$2!=""{printf "%s", $2 $1} END {printf "\n"}'
```

EDIT: Also if you want to get rid of punctuation characters, just add this to `tr`:

```
tr '\n[:punct:]' ' ' < file.txt | fold -w1 | uniq -c | awk '$2!=""{printf "%s", $2 $1} END {printf "\n"}'
```

Comment: A reduced version of this code is working too -

`fold -w1 file.txt | uniq -c | awk '{printf $2 $1}'`

What was the first `tr '\n' ' ' ` used for? 
And I'm not quite familiar with awk. Could you please teach me what's happening at the awk block?

Comment: That first `tr` will convert the input to something that's no longer a valid test file per POSIX (no terminating newline) so YMMV with what any subsequent tool does with it. Also testing `$2` will fail when $2 is 0 (maybe you mean `$2!=""`?), and then `print $2 $1` will fail when the input contains printf formatting chars (always do `printf "%s", $n` instead of `printf $n`).

Comment: I thought it would be important because of the possibility of having multiple lines in `file.txt`; if, let's say, `f` is the last character of line 1 and line 2 starts with `f` again, it would render as `f2` if not for the `tr` command  there.

Comment: @Ed Morton Yes that's what I meant. Thanks for the heads up, I'm updating the answer.

Comment: @BikramAgarwal I'm inverting fields 1 (`$1`) and 2 (`$2`) for generating the pattern you requested with the output from `uniq -c`, which shows first the number of occurrences (of sequential characters) and then the character; also `awk` flattens the output into one contiguous string of characters and, at the end, prints a newline (`END {printf "\n"}`).